# How to verify a bootable USB pendrive?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, linux-mint

There are many OSs that can be written to USB flash drive and result in a bootable USB drive. For security reasons I need to verify the bootable USB that is written from the image file I downloaded. I've looked around the web and there is no answer.

So I have my second question, how to have all the files in folder listed and check their hash with about one command line?

Comment: What exactly is the first question? "How can I verify a bootable USB against the downloaded image?" You should split up multiple questions over multiple entries on this site, especially if they are unrelated. For the second part you might want to look at the `-c` option of `md5sum` resp. `shaXYZsum`.

Comment: Do you write the distribution's ISO image to the flash drive using `dd`, or do you use something like Startup Disk Creator or UNetbootin that may write other things in addition to the ISO image, such as partitioning information or a boot block?

Comment: It is a shame that such an important question is not properly answered. Many people showing (off) all their knowledge but not answering. Too much ego, perhaps... too much superiority... :-(

Answer (score 1):

use md5sum for regular files in the USB flash and redirect the output tp a file

then, do the samething to the files in the image file.

then, compare the results.